# can't resolve import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.events.EventDipatcher

Tags: android

I need the classes Label and EventDispatcher in my code, and searching through the internet I found that they are found in google devtools, however, neither Eclipse, nor Android Studio is able to resolve this library. I've got Google Repository and Google Play Services up to date. Can't find the solution, new to android coding, help?

```
package com.brr.uet.robo;

import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.Component;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.HandlesEventDispatching;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.ActivityStarter;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Button;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Form;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.HorizontalArrangement;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Label;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Notifier;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.events.EventDispatcher;

public class MainActivity extends Form implements HandlesEventDispatching {      
private Label touchZombieLabel;
private HorizontalArrangement horizontalArrangement1;
private Button zombieButton;
private AccelerometerSensor accelerometerSensor1;
}
```

Error says, "Can't resolve symbol 'devtools'"?

Comment: paste your code with import so can check where you going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your imports is like following,may be some wrong imports is there that is why you facing that problem.

```
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Button;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.Component;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.HandlesEventDispatching;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Form;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.HorizontalArrangement;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.components.android.Label;
import com.google.devtools.simple.runtime.events.EventDispatcher;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I didn't have the "libSimpleAndroidRuntime.jar" file added to my libs in the project. Once I added it, everything went smoothly.